# salesforce Report in pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, joined-reports

I need to show the salesforce standard report in pdf format.
please help on this as I tried getting the report into visual force by using

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:outputPanel id="MissingAttRpt" >
<apex:iframe src="/00O28000000aORe?isdtp=lt" scrolling="true"  height="1588px"  width="100%"/>   
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

`isdtp=lt // isdtp =mn`

this is not fetching the report into the page after inspecting I am getting the error

> Refused to display 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/00O28000000aORe?isdtp=mn' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

My Approach  was that if the report is visible on the page then rendering the page in PDF.

Need quick response in this case . Please let me know if my approach is correct in this case or not.

I tried even going for the

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId=""></analytics:reportChart>
```

but this is not my solution as I believe because I need the report in pdf but here the result is in a chart.

Answer (score 1):

We can generate reports in pdf

https://reportbuilder.cloud4j.com/login

Allows you to send and schedule these reports.